# image File Upload Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I am trying from user controls to add the Image

```
  if (this.lbl_mode.Text == "1")
  {
      int Added = offersRepository.AddOffer(RelatedImageName,RelatedUrl, "", ImageName, ImageSmallName, ImageCircleName, IMageAlt, DoctorID, OperationId, SpecialityID, OfferTitle, "", OfferDescription, OriginalPrice, NewPrice, Lang, isTopOffer, Active, "", "", aliasurl, IsAppointmentOffer);
      if (Added != -1)
      {


          if (FileUploadImage.HasFile)
          {
              FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(FileUploadImage.PostedFile.FileName);
              FileUploadImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path + "/" + ImageName.ToString() + FileExtension).ToString());
              // _Helper.GenerateThumbNail(Server.MapPath(path + "/" + Added.ToString() + FileExtension).ToString(), Server.MapPath(path + "/Thumb" + Added.ToString() + FileExtension).ToString(), 370, 201);
              // _Helper.GenerateThumbNail(Server.MapPath(path + "/" + Added.ToString() + FileExtension).ToString(), Server.MapPath(path + "/InnerThumb" + Added.ToString() + FileExtension).ToString(), 370, 201);
              ImageFileExtension = FileExtension;
          }
          Image1.ImageUrl = path + "/" + ImageName.ToString() + FileExtension;
          this.lbl_message.Text = "Offer has been added sucessfuly";
          this.lbl_message.Visible = true;

          if (smallimageFileUpload.HasFile)
          {
              FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(smallimageFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
              smallimageFileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path + "/Small" + ImageSmallName.ToString() + FileExtension).ToString());
              // _Helper.GenerateThumbNail(Server.MapPath(path + "/" + Added.ToString() + FileExtension).ToString(), Server.MapPath(path + "/Small" + Added.ToString() + FileExtension).ToString(), 231, 231);
              SmallFileExtension = FileExtension;
          }
          SmallImage.ImageUrl = path + "/Small" + ImageSmallName.ToString() + FileExtension;
          this.lbl_message.Text = "Speciality has been added sucessfuly";
          this.lbl_message.Visible = true;


          if (iconFileUpload.HasFile)
          {
              FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(iconFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
              iconFileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path + "/Icon" + ImageCircleName.ToString() + FileExtension).ToString());
              //_Helper.GenerateThumbNail(Server.MapPath(path + "/" + Added.ToString() + FileExtension).ToString(), Server.MapPath(path + "/Icon" + Added.ToString() + FileExtension).ToString(), 231, 231);
              IconFileExtension = FileExtension;
          }
          IconImage.ImageUrl = path + "/Icon" + ImageCircleName.ToString() + FileExtension;



          //if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
          //{
          //    FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
          //    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path + "/Related" + RelatedImageName.ToString() + FileExtension).ToString());
          //    //_Helper.GenerateThumbNail(Server.MapPath(path + "/" + Added.ToString() + FileExtension).ToString(), Server.MapPath(path + "/Icon" + Added.ToString() + FileExtension).ToString(), 231, 231);
          //    RelatedExtension = FileExtension;
          //}
          //IconImage.ImageUrl = path + "/Related" + RelatedImageName.ToString() + FileExtension;


          if (RelatedImageFileUpload.HasFile)
          {
              string relatedFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(RelatedImageFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
              string relatedFileName = "RelatedImageName"; // Change this as needed
              RelatedImageFileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path + "/" + relatedFileName + relatedFileExtension));
              // Set the Image control's ImageUrl property to display the uploaded related image
              Image2.ImageUrl = path + "/" + relatedFileName + relatedFileExtension;
              // Store the related image name if needed
              txt_RelatedImageName.Text = relatedFileName + relatedFileExtension;
          }




          offersRepository.UpdateImagePath(Added, path + "/" + ImageName.ToString() + ImageFileExtension, path + "/Small" + ImageSmallName.ToString() + SmallFileExtension, path + "/Icon" + ImageCircleName.ToString() + IconFileExtension, path + "/Offer" + RelatedImageName.ToString() + RelatedExtension);
          this.lbl_message.Text = "Speciality has been added sucessfuly";
          this.lbl_message.Visible = true;

      }
      ClearControl();
  }
```

```
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 35px" valign="top">
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Related Image " Width="130px"></asp:Label></td>
    <td style="width: 1px; font-weight: bold;" valign="top">
        :</td>
    <td style="width: 90%">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" CssClass="error" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1"
            Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Enter Image File" ValidationGroup="AddService" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The Image must be with extension .jpg or .jpeg or .png or .bmp or .webp" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^.+\.((jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|JPG|JPEG|PNG|BMP|svg|webp))$" ValidationGroup="AddChoose"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
     </td>
</tr>
```

then i am making it appear in the front end

```
 @if (@Model.Model.CurrentOffer.RelatedOfferImage != "")
 {
     <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
         <img src="@(Model.Model.CurrentOffer.ImagePath.Replace("~/", "../"))" class="img-fluid mb-4 w-75" alt="" title="" draggable="false" loading="lazy" style="width:40% !important">
         <a href="~/OfferBooking/@(Model.Model.CurrentOffer.RelatedAliasUrl)">
             <img src="@(Model.Model.CurrentOffer.RelatedOfferImage.Replace("~/", "../"))" class="img-fluid mb-4 w-75" alt="" title="" draggable="false" loading="lazy" style="width:40% !important">

         </a>
     </div>

 }
 else
 {
     <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
         <img src="@(Model.Model.CurrentOffer.ImagePath.Replace("~/", "../"))" class="img-fluid mb-4 m-auto w-75" alt="@Model.Model.CurrentOffer.ImageAlt" title="@Model.Model.CurrentOffer.ImageAlt" />
     </div>

 }
```

the related image is not appearing but when i open the database it's added correactly and in the inspect in the page the url in image src is added cooreactly but the image is not visible althogh the other three pics are added correactly

Comment: You're mixing Razor (`@(Model.Etc)` in `.cshtml`) and WebForms (`<%: expr %>` in `.aspx`) - that makes no sense.

Comment: `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="FileUpload1"` <-- Please explain your thought-process as you wrote this...

Comment: The razor page is for the front end and the webForms is for the CPanel it's like a CMS Project

Comment: <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" To make the Image Uploaded is from a specific extension

Comment: There's at least _two things_ wrong with that: `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator>` cannot be used with `<input type="file"/>`, and secondarily: you **must not** rely on checking file-name extrensions to restrict uploaded files (e.g. anyone can rename a `.exe` to `.docx`) - and the preferred way to filter file-input types is by using the `accept=""` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/accept